# pptpd not starting

Tags: vpn, pptpd, sockets

I am working on Ubuntu 11.10. I am getting a error message while starting PPTP VPN server:

```
pptpd[6779] :MGR: Couldn't create host socket
 pptpd[6779]: createHostSocket: Address already in use
```

Comment: Had the same problem.
Appeared, there were two gateways configured in /etc/network/interfaces
Fxied GW's and pptpd started without any trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you assigned an ip address for vpn client? Make sure you have enough spare numbers in local ip and remote ip ranges.